# HTML email sent from PHP script is missing quotes and a letter after the missing quote

Tags: php, html, email

I was able to create an HTML email body and sent the email out and get the email at the other end but somewhere in the way it looses some quotes and a letter right after the lost quote so it does not look right even though the data is there. I escaped the quotes by putting a back-slash before all the quotes but still the same: it removes the back-slash too. In this case I am using single quotes out side and double quotes inside. I Have tried the opposite and still happening.

```
  $message= '
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
      <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Solicitud de registro enviado desde I-Home.es</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #introduccion {
      font-size: 24px;
  }
  td:first-child {
      background-color: #FC9;
      text-align: right;
      width: 30%;
      padding-right: 5px;
  }
  td:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: #FDA;
      text-align: right;
      width: 70%;
      padding-right: 5px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="introduccion">
  '. $subject . '<span> </span> 
  </div>
  <table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>'. $name. ' &nbsp;</td>

      [... more here ...]

      </body>
  </html>
      ' ;
```

This is a clip of the actually received email, note the missing quotes and letters in the "id" and in the "with":

```
  <div id=ntroduccion'>
  I-Home: Solicitud de registro para Amelia<span> </span> 
  </div>
  <table width=00' border='>
```

Comment: We really need to see your code that actually sends the email.

Comment: What are you using to send emails?

Comment: Are you certain the quotes on `id="introduction"` are actual double-quotes, and not some special curly-quote copy/pasted from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a backslash to all quotes within a PHP variable. So \" should always work.

```
<?php
$message= "
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
<title>Solicitud de registro enviado desde I-Home.es</title>
<style type=\"text/css\">
#introduccion {
  font-size: 24px;
}
td:first-child {
  background-color: #FC9;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FDA;
  text-align: right;
  width: 70%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id=\"introduccion\">
'. $subject . '<span> </span> 
</div>
<table width=\"500\" border=\"0\">
<tr>
  <td>Nombre</td>
  <td>'. $name. ' &nbsp;</td>

  [... more here ...]

  </body>
</html>
  " ;
  echo $message;
  ?>
```

Comment: I did, I escaped the quotes by putting a back-slash before all the quotes but still the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use HEREDOC SYNTAX

I've tried this and **working** . Don't forget to set $name , $to etc.

```
$message = <<<MAIL
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Solicitud de registro enviado desde I-Home.es</title>
<style type="text/css">
#introduccion {
font-size: 24px;
}
td:first-child {
background-color: #FC9;
text-align: right;
width: 30%;
padding-right: 5px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
background-color: #FDA;
text-align: right;
width: 70%;
padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="introduccion">
'. $subject . '<span> </span> 
</div>
<table width="500" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Nombre</td>
<td>'. $name. ' &nbsp;</td>

[... more here ...]

</body>
</html>
MAIL;

    // sending mail
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

So, quotes won't get confused. I tried and working very well.

Comment: I noticed that you added <<<MAIL at the begining instead of a sigle quote. Is that another kind of quoting? Also would you mind show me what command you used to send the email? Perhaps is different to the one I am using.

Comment: I'll investigate more about that HEREDOC SYNTAX.

Comment: (Without using heredoc syntax) A test I did displaying the $message string with an 'alert' shows that all the quotes are in fact there before sending the email, so I have the feeling that the problem is the send mail command I am using.

Comment: @Guasqueño Paste the send mail command you speak of. When dealing with PHP and email... Zend is God.

Comment: @Guasqueño , i'm sending mail basically like this : `mail("eray@mailinator.com", "subject", $message);` .HEREDOC is great way to assign complicated string datas to a variable. If you assign strings with HEREDOC method, don't worry about any quote problem :)

Comment: Are you sure, your server really sending mails ?

Answer (score 0):

The elision of '=' characters and some others immediately following looks suspiciously like you have the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) Content-Transfer-Encoding set to quoted-printable.

Change your message headers to use another transfer encoding to avoid the incorrect mapping of the '=' characters, or escape them correctly in the source message.

It is possible your web mail client is less zealous about standards compliance that Outlook and consequently works more like you expect.

Answer (score -1):

As I was kind of sure the problem was not the setting of the php variable (as it worked for Eray) but on the sending, transporting or receiving of the email, I did a test. Instead of sending the email to my Outlook account I sent it to my yahoo web-based account and was surprised to see that it display much better and the quotes are in fact there. So all indicates that the problem is that **MS-Outlook is removing the quotes**. There must be a way to get it right for Outlook (and the web-based email as well) as I have received well formated HTML email in Outlook. I thought of using a library such as the Zend_Mail mentioned above but I feel I am adding additional level of complexity that at the end would be as difficult as what I am trying myself, somehow I have to tell Zand_Mail I am sending HTML and not plain text.

One last note, the email received in **yahoo.com is missing the "(2)"** in the CSS so the back-ground color and alignment is not the right one.

```
td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FDA;
  text-align: right;
  width: 70%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Thanks every body for your help.

NOTE: HEREDOC syntax did not work for me. I used that syntax (not three but two <) for Unix scripts but may not work for PHP. I decided to give Zend_Mail a try.

**UNDATE**

I successfully used Zend_Framework's Mail and Mime libraries but with some difficulties, not because of Zend but because my Web Hosting server provider had the **include_once** and **server side** includes disabled, and it was hard for me to find out that was happening. Zend_Mail sends the email and the quotes are kept.

Comment: Correct. Outlook is probably doing exactly what it should. If the message has a Content-Transfer-Encoding of quoted-printable, then the '=' characters will be stripped when the message is read, resulting in an incorrect HTML payload. Change the encoding to correct the problem. Other mail clients may be more tolerant when they receive messages that are incorrectly formatted.